# AngularJS typeahead throws 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.length')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been struggling with this for the past one day and even though it seems that everybody has this working, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.length')
```

The following is my html:

```
<input ng-model="customerQuery" 
       type="text" 
       typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in searchCustomers($viewValue)"                
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead-on-select="addCustomerToInvoice($item)"
       typeahead-min-length="3"  
       class="form-control"/>
```

here is my service:

```
getCustomers: function(formData) {
  return $http({
      url: '/api/sales/searchCustomer',
      data: {name: formData},
      method: 'POST',
      header: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
  });
}
```

and finally here is my controller:

```
$scope.searchCustomers = function(customer) {
    SalesService.getCustomers(customer)
    .then(
      function(response) {
        if (response.data.message) {
          console.log(response.data.message);
        }
        else {
          return limitToFilter(response.data, 10);
        }

      },
      function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      }
    );
};
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure without a running reproduce scenario but one thing that is obviously wrong is that you are not returning results of your service call from the `searchCustomers` in your controller. It should go something like:

```
$scope.searchCustomers = function(customer) {
    return SalesService.getCustomers(customer)
    .then(
      function(response) {
        if (response.data.message) {
          console.log(response.data.message);
        }
        else {
          return limitToFilter(response.data, 10);
        }

      },
      function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      }
    );
};
```

There might be more to it than just this omission so send a reproduce scenario if there are any remaining issues after this fix.